# how to find files in a library(I'm a starter)

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, powershell-2.0

I wanna use powershell to get all the file in sharepoint library "EM_DOC_LIBRARY" and their file names. But I totally have no ideas about how to do that, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is lightweight script for what you want:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
$web = Get-SPWeb http://servername/subweb
$l = $web.Lists["EM_DOC_LIBRARY"]
$l.Items | ? { $_.Name -eq "yourfilename.txt" } | %{ $item = $l.GetItemByID($_.ID); $item.Delete(); }
```

Comment: but you still would need to load the DLL... `[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") `

Comment: ok, thanks, I forgot that one.

Comment: so if I say, I wanna find the file with "helloworld.psl" and delete it, how would I write?(it's my first day work, lol)

Comment: @user1456899 Sorry bro, we're not here to write your code for ya ;) Google however, is your friend.

Comment: @user1456899 I agree with pixelbobby. Try to play with it. Explore sharepoint object model. Explore sharepoint cmdlets. (I edited my answer to delete the file anyway)

Comment: @user1456899 also, please consider checking one of these since we both tried to help you.

Answer (score 3):

In the future, we want you to at least check Google and try to start scripting this out yourself.  But I'm feeling slightly altruistic today.  Here's some code that should point you in the right direction...

Also, definitely checkout [**Hey Scripting Guy's Blog**](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/) for more PowerShell / SharePoint kung-fu.

**Get a Specific List Item by ID**

```
## this is how you load the native SharePoint DLL to Powershell (On Server)
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") 

$url = “http://mysite.myurl.com”
$listName = "EM_DOC_LIBRARY"
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$list = $web.Lists[$listName]
$listitem = $web.Lists[$listName].Items.GetItemByID($litem)
```

**More Example Code | Get Large Files on SharePoint Farm**

```
function Get-DocInventory() {
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
    $farm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local
    foreach ($spService in $farm.Services) {
        if (!($spService -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService])) {
            continue;
        }

        foreach ($webApp in $spService.WebApplications) {
            if ($webApp -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication]) { continue }

            foreach ($site in $webApp.Sites) {
                foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) {
                    foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {
                        if ($list.BaseType -ne "DocumentLibrary") {
                            continue
                        }
                        foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
                            $data = @{
                                "Web Application" = $webApp.ToString()
                                "Site" = $site.Url
                                "Web" = $web.Url
                                "list" = $list.Title
                                "Item ID" = $item.ID
                                "Item URL" = $item.Url
                                "Item Title" = $item.Title
                                "Item Created" = $item["Created"]
                                "Item Modified" = $item["Modified"]
                                "Size (kb)" = $item.File.Length/1KB
                                "Size (gb)" = $item.File.Length/1GB

                            }

                            Write-Host $item.Url -ForegroundColor DarkGray

                            # Only add files larger than 100 MB
                            if($item.File.Length -gt 100MB){
                                Write-Host $site.Url + $item.Url -ForegroundColor Red
                                New-Object PSObject -Property $data
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $web.Dispose();
                }
                $site.Dispose()
            }
        }
    }
}
#Get-DocInventory | Out-GridView
Get-DocInventory | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path D:\Logs\inventory.csv
```